# Fetch Image from URL

Tags: ios, objective-c

please tell me the code for navigation background image which image should get from URL ,
I have tried this code

```
NSURL *urlTop = [NSURL URLWithString:ImgUrlInner];
NSData *urlDataTop = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlTop];
UIImage *imageTop = [UIImage imageWithData:urlDataTop];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage``:imageTop forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Please explain what errors you get or what is the problems with the code... Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to know more about asking good question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just i did getting image and display in navigation bar. Its working code.

```
    NSURL *urlNav = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlNav];
    UIImage *imageNav = [UIImage imageWithData:urlData];

    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:NextView];
    //navController.navigationBarHidden=YES;

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:imageNav forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```